# Makefile seems to be compiling files in the wrong order

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, gnu-make

I created a makefile on my own as a tutorial testing various features. It seems that I have an error though since it gives me the output:

```
    g++  src/test1.o -o dcpu-16
src/test1.o: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
src/test1.o: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
src/test1.o: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
src/test1.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
src/test1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x10): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
src/test1.o: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
src/test1.o:(.data+0x10): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in src/test1.o(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:35: recipe for target 'dcpu-16' failed
make: *** [dcpu-16] Error 1
```

The makefile used is this:

```
WARNINGS := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align \
            -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations \
            -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wno-long-long \
            -Wuninitialized -Wconversion -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function

CC   := gcc
CXX  := g++ 
LD   := g++
CP   := cp

SOURCES:=$(shell find src/ -name "*.cpp")

OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
DEPFILES := $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)
GARBAGE := core core.* *.stackdump ./tags $(EXECUTABLE)

EXECUTABLE=dcpu-16

OPTFLAGS  := -g -O3
CFLAGS   += $(OPTFLAGS) $(WARNINGS)
CXXFLAGS += $(CFLAGS)
LDFLAGS=

ifeq ($(DEBUG_BUILD),1)
    CFLAGS +=-DDEBUG_BUILD
endif

.PHONY: clean all

default: $(EXECUTABLE)

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(LD) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean: 
    rm -rf $(EXECUTABLE) $(OBJECTS) $(GARBAGE) $(DEPFILES)
```

What is it that I messed up exactly on the makefile above and is it any good in general or has it any other flaws other than the immediate compilation issue?

Comment: You need to only compile, and not link for `.cpp.o`, so it should read `$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@` (oops, CXX, not CC)

Comment: @Petesh question updated, this does not seem to solve the problem but it changes the output.

Comment: did you `make clean` before re-running `make`? make will only rebuild based on dependent files, and that output indicates that it didn't recompile the `.cpp` file into a `.o` file

Comment: You are correct, can you add this as an answer so I can accept it, including the first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a purely technical perspective the line making the `.o` is erroneous in that it had:

```
.cpp.o:
    $(LD) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

This would cause the production of a file intended to be linked that has already been linked; therefore a bunch of extra values would be injected into `.o` file which would not be expected when it comes to the linking step:

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
```

So, let's get the terminology for the makefiles in order - compiling is using either the `C` or `C++` compiler, which generally involves using the variables `CC` or `CXX`, so we're just compiling the `.cpp` files into `.o` files, so we should compile using the C++ compiler, and the C++ flags:

```
.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Making the changes to the `Makefile` doesn't cause the already built files to suddenly become invalid (unless we made all the files depend on the Makefile), so you need to clean up what's already been compiled - you would have had a `.o` file that had been built incorrectly, an invocation of `make clean` will remove this `.o` file so that a subsequent invocation of make would rebuild it.

As for some stylistic items for the `Makefile`; you generally do:

- `CFLAGS` == flags for the C compiler *only*
- `CXXFLAGS` == flags for the C++ compiler *only*
- `CPPFLAGS` == flags for the C preprocessor *only*

You can use `make -p` to dump out the default database for make, which would indicate it's default compile and link lines for various file types, and it shows:

```
.cpp.o:
#  Builtin rule
#  Implicit rule search has not been done.
#  Modification time never checked.
#  File has not been updated.
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

COMPILE.cpp = $(COMPILE.cc)

COMPILE.cc = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
```

You can build on these built-in rules, in order to reduce the amount of code you need to write in your makefile